# Language Switcher made in Svelte not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte-3

I am currently learning svelte 3, I wanted to do a project that was going to be published on github in english but I have friends that dont speak english, so I tried making a language switcher.

This is my attempt at it:

```
<script lang="typescript">
  var selectedLang = "en_us";
  const _lang_filename = "./lang/%.json".replace("%", selectedLang);
  import lang from _lang_filename;
</script>

<div id="_app_">
  <h1>{lang.welcome}</h1>

  <button
    on:click={() => {
      selectedLang = "pt_br";
    }}>Português (Brasil)</button
  >
  <button
    on:click={() => {
      selectedLang = "en_us";
    }}>English (United States)</button
  >
</div>
```

on the import of the lang file, it gives out an error when i put a variable: Unexpected Token, I have tried to put the string.replace() on the import itself but it also does not work.

Comment: why not import both files and switch betwen them with an if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is a misunderstanding of how Svelte works.

Unlike other frameworks, the part between `<script>` and `</script>` is only executed **once**. This means that no matter how often you press that button, `lang_filename` will **never** change.  In order to tell the compiler that one variable depends on another you have to mark it as reactive using `$:`.

```js
let selectedLang = "en_us";
$: _lang_filename = "./lang/%.json".replace("%", selectedLang);
```

now `_lang_filename` will update when `selectedLang` changes.

(note: I would use template literals here)

```js
$: _lang_filename = `./lang/${selectedLang}.json`
```

Now that you have the correct filename, we have to load the actual file.  To do so you can do a dynamic `import`, but the html specs refuse to import anything else than `javascript` file this way.

You can however work around this by using `fetch` to get the file instead. So now you have to declare a variable `lang` to hold your language object, and a loader function to load it.

```js
let lang = {}
function load(filename) {
  lang = await fetch(filename).then(res => res.json())
}
```

All that is left is to tell Svelte to rerun `load` whenever the filename changes, this again can be achieved by using reactivity:

```js
$: load(filename)
```

We could very well just pass in *selectedLang* here and construct the path in the load function of course.

For completeness sake here would be the entire script:

```html
<script>
    let selectedLang = "en_us";
    let lang = {}

    $: loadLanguage(selectedLang)

    async function loadLanguage() {
        lang = await fetch(`./lang/${selectedLang}.json`).then(res => res.json())
    }
</script>
```

Important to note though is that at first `lang` will be a completely empty object, this will give a flash of having `undefined` everywhere.